# Shell script to run on folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a request to run manintenance.

I have a exe file in d folder and that exe file should run on file in different folder on different drive.

exe file path: d:\notes\ncompact.exe
and it should run on folder in E drive and maintenance should run on files starting with number 1
e:\notes\data\1*.nsf

please give me the script for this

Added from comments:

```
@echo off 
Start D:\notes\nserver.exe -q >> D:\logs\quitDomino.txt 
pause 
net stop "Lotus Domino Server (ENotesData)" >> D:\logs\lotusservice.txt 
Pause 
echo %date% %time% >> D:\logs\updall.txt 
pause 
Start D:\notes\ncompact.exe -c -i "E:\notes\data\state\1*.nsf" >> D:\logs\bes1.txt 
echo %date% %time% >> D:\logs\bes1.txt 
pause 
Start D:\notes\ncompact.exe -c -i "E:\notes\data\state\2*.nsf" >> D:\logs\bes2.txt 
echo %date% %time% >> D:\logs\bes1.txt 
end
```

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far, and what *specific* problem do you need help with?

Comment: @echo off
Start D:\notes\nserver.exe -q >> D:\logs\quitDomino.txt
pause
net stop "Lotus Domino Server (ENotesData)" >> D:\logs\lotusservice.txt
Pause
echo %date% %time% >> D:\logs\updall.txt
pause
Start D:\notes\ncompact.exe -c -i "E:\notes\data\state\1*.nsf" >> D:\logs\bes1.txt
echo %date% %time% >> D:\logs\bes1.txt
pause
Start D:\notes\ncompact.exe -c -i "E:\notes\data\state\2*.nsf" >> D:\logs\bes2.txt
echo %date% %time% >> D:\logs\bes1.txt
end

Comment: this is what i had tried, my code is failing when doing compact on files in state folder

Comment: I don't see a Powershell expression anywhere in the question.

Comment: If you have batch code you want to include edit your question with the code. Code looks terrible in comments. Also change the tag to batch while you are updating your post

Comment: Is E: a mapped network drive?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your program `D:\notes\ncompact.exe` doesn't understand wildcards.

It's been maybe 8 years since I've written batch files.  However, the `for /f` command should allow you to do what you want.

Try this:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions
Start D:\notes\nserver.exe -q >> D:\logs\quitDomino.txt 
pause 
net stop "Lotus Domino Server (ENotesData)" >> D:\logs\lotusservice.txt 
Pause 
echo %date% %time% >> D:\logs\updall.txt 
pause 

for /f %%f in (E:\notes\data\state\1*.nsf) do ( Start D:\notes\ncompact.exe -c -i %%f >> D:\logs\bes1.txt )

echo %date% %time% >> D:\logs\bes1.txt 
pause 

for /f %%f in (E:\notes\data\state\2*.nsf) do ( Start D:\notes\ncompact.exe -c -i %%f >> D:\logs\bes2.txt  )

echo %date% %time% >> D:\logs\bes1.txt 
end
```

Note that you might need to use `%f` instead of `%%f` if you run that from the command line instead of a batch file.  As I said, it's been a long time.  I also added the `setlocal enableextensions` command.  I don't remember if that's necessary for `for /f` or not anymore.